# Making a Wordpress plugin with sqlite database (PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress, sqlite

I am making a very simple PHP plugin so that I can read the data from a table and show it on my wordpress website footer. ( I am not a PHP developer and not very familiar with it's syntax)

```html
$connection = new SQLite3('timetable.db');

$today = date("d/m");
$todayDate = (string)$today;

$sql = <<<HEREDOC
SELECT morning, morning, evening
FROM manchester
where date = :date
HEREDOC;

$rs = $connection->prepare($sql);

$rs->bindValue(':date', $todayDate, SQLITE3_TEXT);
$result = $rs->execute();

function praytime_shortcode_fn() { 
while($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
  echo "morning = ". $row['morning'] . "<br>";
  echo "afternoon = ". $row['morning'] ."<br>";
  echo "evening = ". $row['evening'] ."<br>";
}


}

add_shortcode( 'praytime', 'praytime_shortcode_fn' );
```

As you can see I am using the praytime short code to display the while loop in my website. However it throws out error every time I enable it on my wordpress website.

Error seems to be to do with use of SQLite library. I have tried linking the database by giving the full path but still didn't work.

**(the code works on it's own on a local machine, so the database and the queries are fine)**

Do you have any suggestions? I would be really grateful./Thanks

Comment: `$result` is not available in that function scope. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Does the web server have sqllite enabled in your php.ini file?

Comment: @Scuzzy If I add  global $result;  after $result and under the $result = $rs->execute(); would it fix the scope issue?

Comment: I would reccomend moving your database requests into your `praytime_shortcode_fn` function so they are not seperate at all. your variable naming convention is a bit too generic to be in the main scope I think.

Comment: @Scuzzy Thank you very much for the advice.

Comment: @jeff thank you, actually the database issue was php support for sqlite3. Thank you.